# Why does the network card on a Linux system boot on its own?

Tags: linux, networking, telnet

When I was using Telnet to remotely access my target computer on Windows and conducting latency testing with `cyclictest`, after several hours of execution, I suddenly found that the `telnet` connection was interrupted:

```
C:\Users\guoya>telnet 192.168.5.1
...
遗失对主机的连接。(Lost connection to host)
```

At this time, I saw the following message appearing on my target computer, as if the network card `eth2` had been restarted:

```
[18825.382832] asix 1-6:1.0 eth2: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
```

However, at this time, no one or any other process was operating the target device. Of course, there is no process operating `eth2` at this moment.

My target computer is using a system that I compiled kernel 6.4.0 to generate `bzImage` and compiled `busybox` to generate the root file system,

```
# taskset -c 2 cyclictest -p 80 -t 1 -n -i 1000 -l 100000000000
/dev/cpu_dma_latency set to 0us
policy: fifo: loadavg: 1.36 1.22 1.14 1/127 1617

T: 0 ( 1553) P:80 I:1000 C:11258227 Min:      2 Act:    3 Avg:    3 Max:      21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels more like a hardware issue, but it's not really possible to tell with only one information line.

Are there one or more routers (or switches) between your client and target machines? Any of them could have restarted.

Have you checked all the intervening network cables? One of them might be loose.

Comment: The connection between Windows and the computer is direct, passing through a USB hub, but not through any other routing devices. The network cable used for connection has not been moved and has been checked for looseness.

Comment: Through a USB hub?  You're aware that many Operating Systems shut down USB interfaces when screensavers or other power-saving subsystems kick in, aren't you?  I often return to my idle laptop and pick up my optical mouse and see the light turn on a half-second after I picked it up - either the USB hub in the laptop or the OS powered the mouse's port down to save energy when there's been no activity on the keyboard and mouse.  This seems likely to have happened to you.